# How to make new field with new characters

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, numbering

I want to add 0 (zero) to existing field.
I have textual field with numbers, sort ascending, 1-100:

1
2
...
13
14
...
99
100
I want to make field like this:
001
002
...
013
014
...
099
100

Is it possible to do this with some function (trim or somehow)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use something like the following expression:

```
right(concat('000', "field_name" ), 3)
```

---

Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: That is, that's what I need.

Comment: @nagib - Most welcome, glad it helped :)